# Scope Results in mongoose by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a hard time trying to achieve this results for days. I hope someone can help me here.

Results I want to achieve. Btw I'm using mongoose/mongodb/node.js

```
{
   "2020-01-12": [
      {
         "user_id": 1234,
         "firstName": "John Doe"
         "createdAt": 2021-01-12T05:45:50.898Z
      },
      {
         "user_id": 1233,
         "firstName" "Jane Doe",
         "createdAt": 2021-01-12T06:45:50.898Z
      }
   ], 
   "2020-01-13": [
      {
       "user_id": 1232,
       "firstName" "Jeff Doe",
       "createdAt" 2021-01-13T05:45:50.898Z
      }
   ]
}
```

**My sample schema**

const User = {
table: 'User',
schema: {
_id: {
name : 'Id',
type: db.keyType(),
required: true
},
firstName: {
name: 'FirstName',
type: String,
required: true,
}
}

**Here's my sample code.**

```
Users.find({ createdAt: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate.setHours(endDate.getHours() + 23) }}).sort({ createdAt: 'asc'}).then(results => {
                 

                    res.status(200).json({
                        results
                    })
```

**URL**: api/users/days/?start_date=2021/01/12&end_date=2021/01/15

I want to scope my data by date but I can't achieve it using mongoose. Thanks in advance if you can help me with this. Its okay if you can help me understand the logic on how to achieve so I can fully understand what I need to learn to get this results so I can research for it. ty very much

Also my **date format is like this ** 2021-01-13T05:45:50.898Z

Comment: Please provide an example of your schema. Also the output provided is not a valid json. I've understood you want something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lB9zY22hKoR), I don't know if it is the expected behavior. But please, update your answer with more details.

Comment: Hello, I've updated my code hope it make sense. I hope you help me what I'm missing :(

Comment: Yes. I want something like that but I want the date to be object keys without "_id". 

[
  {
     "2021-01-18",
    "createdAt": [
      {
        "createdAt": "2021-01-18",
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastName": "doe"
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2021-01-18",
        "firstName": "Philip",
        "lastName": "Stewart"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
     "2021-01-19",
    "createdAt": [
      {
        "createdAt": "2021-01-19",
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "doe"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: You think its possible?

Comment: Also my date format is 2021-01-13T05:45:50.898Z